# ¿Como hacer que un objeto aparezca en diferentes posiciones con pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

estoy intentando hacer un proyecto para prácticar que consiste en un juego en el que el jugador puede mover una nave con las teclas y tiene que tratar de evitar chocar con unos asteroides. El problema es que quiero que los asteroides aparezcan en posiciones aleatorias y intenté este código, pero se crea una nueva posición cada vez que se ejecuta el while loop y no se como hacer para que aparezca uno y después de un tiempo cambie de posición. Agradecería ayuda.

```
def dibujar_window (espacio_ocupado):
WINDOW.blit(ESPACIO_FONDO, (0, 0))
WINDOW.blit(NAVE, (espacio_ocupado.x, espacio_ocupado.y))
WINDOW.blit(METEORIO, (randint(0, WIDTH), randint(0, HEIGHT)))
pygame.display.update()

def main ():
espacio_ocupado = pygame.Rect(50, HEIGHT//2, WIDTH_NAVE, HEIGHT_NAVE)
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
salud = 1
run  = True
while run:
    reloj.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == CHOCAR_METEORITO:
            salud -=1
    pantalla_final = ''
    if salud <=0:
        pantalla_final = 'Perdiste'
    if pantalla_final != 'Perdiste':
        mostrar_pantalla_final(pantalla_final)
    
    dibujar_window(espacio_ocupado)
    teclas_presionadas = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    controlador_movimiento(teclas_presionadas, espacio_ocupado)
pygame.quit()
```

Si se necesita más especificación o algo avisar es que soy nuevo aquí

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu bucle de eventos llamas la función `dibujar_window`, que a su vez asigna una posición aleatoria al meteorito. La idea es que el meteorito tenga una posición fija, y que se actualice en ciertos casos. Ejemplo, que se actualice cuando hay un choque:

```
def actualizar_pos_meteorito():
  return ((randint(0, WIDTH), randint(0, HEIGHT))

pos_meteorito = actualizar_pos_meteorito()

def dibujar_window (espacio_ocupado):
  WINDOW.blit(ESPACIO_FONDO, (0, 0))
  WINDOW.blit(NAVE, (espacio_ocupado.x, espacio_ocupado.y))
  WINDOW.blit(METEORIO, pos_meteorito ))
  pygame.display.update()

def main ():
espacio_ocupado = pygame.Rect(50, HEIGHT//2, WIDTH_NAVE, HEIGHT_NAVE)
reloj = pygame.time.Clock()
salud = 1
run  = True
while run:
    reloj.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            run = False
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == CHOCAR_METEORITO:
            salud -=1
            actualizar_pos_meteorito()
    pantalla_final = ''
    if salud <=0:
        pantalla_final = 'Perdiste'
    if pantalla_final != 'Perdiste':
        mostrar_pantalla_final(pantalla_final)
    
    dibujar_window(espacio_ocupado)
    teclas_presionadas = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    controlador_movimiento(teclas_presionadas, espacio_ocupado)
pygame.quit()
```